# How to get distinct word count of number of filed in a csv file

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, scripting

As you can see, I have 3 fields in this file, but there may be a comma in the countries. So, I don't want it be considered as a field. That's why I want to get the distinct word count of number of filed in this file.

```
ankit.rohilla Desktop $ head RandomizerCodes20210520.csv
Effective Date,Number,Country
05/25/2021,186800881,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800885,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800893,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800870,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800876,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800181,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800110,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800125,Trinidad and Tobago
05/25/2021,186800172,Trinidad and Tobago
ankit.rohilla Desktop $
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: If you're asking for help parsing input that has commas in the country name then include lines that have commas in the country name in your sample input/output to a) demonstrate the problem you're asking for help with, and b) give us something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the solution to this would be:

```
ankit.rohilla Desktop $ awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print NF}' RandomizerCodes20210520.csv | uniq -c
1408720 3
ankit.rohilla Desktop $
```

Where 3 was the value I was looking for and 1408720 is the word count of this file.

Comment: In shell you should always use single quotes around all strings unless you need double quotes or no quotes for some specific purpose (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). If you follow that advice then `-F"\"*,\"*"` (and many other things) becomes simpler, `-F'"*,"*'`.

Comment: There is a simpler solution by the way, once you fix your question we can help you.